# Loading Tensorflow Model in React

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm a rewriting a simple testing app that was built just using HTML, CSS and javascript in React. I keep getting a `Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Failed to parse model JSON of response from ../public/model/model.json. Please make sure the server is serving valid JSON for this request.` with eh following code:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
let model;

(async () => {
    model = await tf.loadGraphModel('../public/model/model.json');
    if(model && model.predict) {
        console.log('Model has predict method');
    }
})();
export default model;
```

Edit: To clarify, I have used the same model in my previous app and did not have issues loading. I have tried loading a saved google model from their site and it works. I'm still not clear as to why the local model fails to load.

Comment: Check if the JSON in the `model.json` file is valid. https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I used this same model in my previous work. Did not have any issues.